# Configuré un PendingIntent pero parece no tomarlo en cuenta al abrir la aplicación

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, push-notification

Configuré un PendingIntent, pero parece no tomarlo en cuenta al ejecutarlo, el PendingIntent está configurado para abrir una clase que no es la principal, pero siempre abre la clase principal.

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService{

private static final String REG_TOKEN = "REG_TOKEN";
public static final String TAG = "NOTICIAS";

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(MyFirebaseMessagingService.this, registro.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        intent.putExtra("Mensaje", remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        notificationBuilder.setContentTitle("Sección 15");
        notificationBuilder.setContentText(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
        notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo);
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(0,notificationBuilder.build());

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que registro.class es una activity, añadida en el manifiesto, el único problema que puedo ver es el tipo de flags que le estas poniendo al intent, yo utilizo:

```
Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
```

y en algún caso combinado con:

```
Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
```

Depende de lo que quieras hacer si crear varias activities vivas a la vez o sustituir a otra.

Comment: Lo que necesito es que cuando yo reciba una notificacion push al dar clic en ella me mande a la clase registro, pero siempre ejecuta la principal, cuando la aplicación esta en abierta y recibes la notificación si te envía a la clase registro, pero si esta en segundo plano, se vuelve a abrir la aplicación y te manda a la clase principal.